# SqlQuery to display the value which is not bull from two rows with same ID

Tags: sql-server

Here I Have one ID having different Codes, I have to display if the Id has a Code value then need to display the code value row  else null value row.

| ID | Code | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | null | Three |
| 12 | 2345 | Three |
| 13 | null | four |
| 14 | 1543 | rewq |

Comment: Please show your current SQL attempt, along with sample data and expected results

Comment: just to make it clear,
you want to display the ID only IF Code is not null ?

Comment: if code is not null then i need to display                                                                                        12 2345 Three   if code is null then                                                                      
  12 null   Three

Comment: Can you have more than 2 rows with the same ID, what do you need to display then ?

Comment: You need to show us sample data, expected outcome and what you have tried to solve it. Then tell us where you are stuck

Comment: it should have always 2 rows or only one row with code with value or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially we want to lookup up and pick out the entire "first" row giving precedence to a non-null. (The logic would be easy to reverse in all of the options below.) These all then go with the assumption that a maximum of two rows can be present and that one of them must have a null `Code` in that case.

```
with data as (select *, count(*) over (partition by ID) as cnt from T)
select ID, Code, Value from data
where cnt = 1 or Code is not null;
```

or

```
select distinct t1.ID,
    coalesce(t2.Code, t1.Code) as Code, coalesce(t2.Value, t1.Value) as Value
from T t1 left outer join T t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.Code is not null;
```

or

```
--SQL Server
select ID, Code, Value
from T t1 cross apply (
    select 1 as Keep from T t2
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    having case when     t1.Code  is null then 0 else 1 end =
           case when max(t2.Code) is null then 0 else 1 end) v;
```

or

```
with data as (select *, max(Code) over (partition by ID) as maxCode from T)
select ID, Code, Value from data
where coalesce(Code, '!@#') = coalesce(maxCode, '!@#');
```

or

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ID
            order by case when Code is not null then 0 else 1 end) as rn
    from T
) select ID, Code, Value from data where rn = 1;
```

or

```
with data as (
    select distinct ID,
        max(Code) over (partition by ID) as Code,
        first_value(Value) over (
            partition by ID
            order by case when Code is not null then 0 else 1 end) as Value
    from T
) select * from data;
```

or

```
select * from T t1
where Code is not null or not exists
    (select 1 from T t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.Code is not null);
```

or

```
select ID, max(Code) as Code,
    /* works better with character values */
    substring(max(left(coalesce(Code, '') + '          ', 10) + Value), 10, 50)
from T group by ID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c08e5bd0b67118d39cf9f6404218b09

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me
SELECT * FROM tablename

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).